# Why ternary operation gives nullpointer while its ifelse counterpart doesn't?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

I am getting NullPointerException in one instance below while its counterpart runs smooth.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(withTernary(null, null)); //Null Pointer
    System.out.println(withIfElse(null, null));  //No Exception
}

private static Boolean withTernary(String val, Boolean defVal){
    return val == null ? defVal : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val);
}

private static Boolean withIfElse(String val, Boolean defVal){
    if (val == null) return defVal;
    else return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val);
}
```

[Online version](http://ideone.com/t5u56o)

[Online version with the lines in `main` reversed](http://ideone.com/uhNKiC), which outputs `null` from `withIfElse` and then fails in `withTernary`.

I am using following java version

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: @Raedwald: Of what?  Why not mark it as such?

Comment: That is _really_ goddamn confusing. This is very much a corner case in the JLS...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the relevant quote from [the spec (§15.25.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.1):

> Boolean conditional expressions are standalone expressions ([§15.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)).
>
> The type of a boolean conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - If the second and third operands are both of type `Boolean`, the conditional expression has type `Boolean`.
> - Otherwise, the conditional expression has type `boolean`.

Therefore, the overall expression's type is considered to be `boolean`, and the `Boolean` value is autounboxed, causing a `NullPointerException`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, why doesn't the following raise an exception?

```
return val == null ? null : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val);
```

Well, the above excerpt from the spec specifically only applies to *boolean conditional expressions,* which are specified [here (§15.25)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If both the second and the third operand expressions are *boolean expressions*, the conditional expression is a boolean conditional expression.
>
> For the purpose of classifying a conditional, the following expressions are boolean expressions:
>
> - An expression of a standalone form ([§15.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)) that has type `boolean` or `Boolean`.
> - A parenthesized `boolean` expression ([§15.8.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5)).
> - A class instance creation expression ([§15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)) for class `Boolean`.
> - A method invocation expression ([§15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)) for which the chosen most specific method ([§15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) has return type `boolean` or `Boolean`.
>   (Note that, for a generic method, this is the type before instantiating the method's type arguments.)
> - A `boolean` conditional expression.

Since `null` is not a *boolean expression*, the overall conditional expression is not a *boolean conditional expression*. Referring to Table 15.2 (later in the same section), we can see that such an expression is considered to have a `Boolean` type, so no unboxing occurs, and no exception is raised.

Comment: Then this "return val == null ? null : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val);" should also fail but it doesn't. Right?

Comment: @DKSRathore I've updated my answer to explain that case.

Answer (score 7):

`val == null ? defVal : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val)` - in this expression, the third argument is `boolean`, and since the ternary operator must have one static type, it will try to unbox the `null`, hence the NPE. Only the assignment to `Boolean` will cause boxing again.
Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Comment: I am finding no NullPointer in return val == null ? null : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val);. Why?

Comment: The NPE happens when you tried with Boolean. Compiler tried to unbox 'Boolean' with null value to 'boolean'. Hence the NPE. Here the third operand has correct value, simple

Answer (score 4):

Because autounboxing. Java derive common type for `defVal` and `"true".equalsIgnoreCase(val)`. Type of first is Boolean, but second boolean. For unknown reason it thinks that common type will be boolean (You can find rule in spec).

Answer (score 3):

This could be explained if `defVal` is `null`.

With ternary expressions, both options must be of exactly the same type and if not some coercion is applied:

The [JLS 15.25 "Conditional operator ? :"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) says:

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

In the case of this expression:

```
val == null ? defVal : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val)
```

The `Boolean` value for `defVal` is auto-unboxed to match the `boolean` result of the string comparison. This is despite the fact that the result of the ternary is then auto-boxed back to a `Boolean` - when deciding how to cast, a ternary does not consider anything outside itself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Let's try in this way

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(withTernary(null, null));
}

private static Boolean withTernary(String val, Boolean defVal){
  return (val == null ? defVal : Boolean.valueOf("true".equalsIgnoreCase(val)));
}
```

Now it will works fine. Now there is no `unboxing` here and will not give you exception. 
But in other way due to `null` `unbox` you will get `NPE`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(withTernary(null, null)); //Null Pointer
}

private static Boolean withTernary(String val, Boolean defVal){
    return (val == null ? defVal : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(val));
}
```