# Is this a scenario where a java boolean can be null? Why does this code compile?

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-operator

We recently ran into a bug in production that I found to be very interesting.  My longtime understanding is that a Java boolean can only be false, or true.  However, it seems in a Ternary Operator it can ultimately resolve to null, and it never produced a compile error, and built all the way to production.  I'm very suprised the following code does not generate a compile error.  Does anyone know why it compiles just fine?  Imho it should not compile! The value it ultimately resolves to is a native boolean.

```
boolean por = (str == null || str.length() == 0) ? null : "true".equalsIgnoreCase(str);
```

Comment: `boolean` or `Boolean`? If it's indeed the primitive, you can expect a `NullPointerException` at runtime in the case the expression evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @ernest_k I think the question is why is it a runtime error and not a compilation error.

Comment: @DaveNewton I see.

Comment: [This post answers your question completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929074/5761558) but I'm not sure the question is a duplicate.

Comment: For the record, although it does not respond to the question you actually asked, that expression is an abomination.  If the intention is that the `null` be interpreted as false, then `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` is all you need.  It's ok with `null` arguments (returning false in that case), and of course an empty string is not a special case in the first place.  So just plain `boolean por = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(str);` would have saved you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 7):

> Does anyone know why it compiles just fine?

Ultimately, because of autoboxing / autounboxing.

When the compiler processes a ternary expression, it uses the second and third operands to choose the result type of the expression.  In your case, the second has null type and the third has (primitive) `boolean` type.  These are not directly compatible, but because of autoboxing, both are compatible with type `Boolean`.  The result of the expression therefore has type `Boolean`, which *does* support `null`.

Because of auto*un*boxing, it is allowed to assign a value of type `Boolean` to a variable of type `boolean`, ***but*** this will fail with a `NullPointerException` in the event that the value being assigned is null, just as if you had invoked the `booleanValue()` method on it.  I presume that this is the error you observed in production.

This is one of the gotchas of autoboxing.

Comment: @user3604456 Very clear. This is ther reason one should use an IDE plugin like SonarLint, or SonarQube on the integration server.

Comment: If this is the case, and it was caused by autoboxing then auto-unboxing, then why wasn't the final result that was assigned to por false?  how could it possibly be null, when the data type is a primitive "boolean"? It should be true, or false, nothing else. You said it assigns a value of Boolean to boolean, but if it did, then it should have assigned it a value of "false". To me, this is a flaw.

Comment: @user3604456, it is among the characteristics of the wrapper classes such as `Boolean` that, as reference types, they can take the value `null`.  It is also among the characteristics of the wrapper classes that attempting to unbox `null` is invalid.  There are languages with looser type semantics than Java's that provide a `null` analogue that is falsey, but Java has only one falsey value (`false`) and only one truthy value (`true`).  You can consider that as flawed as you want, but it's the way it is.  For what it's worth, though, it has legitimate uses, such as implementing ternary logic.